# How to create a passcode view iphone

Tags: iphone, view, passwords, controller, screen

I'd like to add a passcode lock in my app...
I created the view but I don't know how to get it working...

This is what I'd like it must do:
- If an user is setting his passcode, he must type it twice and the code must verify if the passcode typed the second time is the same of the first time.
- If the passcode controller is called by a setting view, for example, to set the passcode, it must have a cancel button on the navigation bar but if it is called at app launch, the cancel button mustn't be enabled.

summaryLabel is the label that show a message like "Passcode didn't match. Try again." when the passcode is not the same as the one written previously or saved.

**EDIT1:** How can I use textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString method to do this?

This is the code:

```
#import "PasscodeController.h"
```

@implementation PasscodeController

@synthesize panelView;
@synthesize summaryLabel;
@synthesize titleLabel;
@synthesize textField1;
@synthesize textField2;
@synthesize textField3;
@synthesize textField4;
@synthesize hiddenTF;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
self.title = @"Passcode"; 
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 22, 270, 30)];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:66.0/255.0 green:85.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:titleLabel];
[titleLabel release];

summaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 130, 270, 40)];
summaryLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
summaryLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
summaryLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentNone;
summaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
summaryLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:66.0/255.0 green:85.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
summaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:summaryLabel];
[summaryLabel release];

textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 60, 60, 60)];
textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
textField1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textField1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
textField1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:41];
textField1.secureTextEntry = YES;
textField1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textField1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
[self.view addSubview:textField1];
[textField1 release];

textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95, 60, 60, 60)];
textField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
textField2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textField2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
textField2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:41];
textField2.secureTextEntry = YES;
textField2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textField2.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
[self.view addSubview:textField2];
[textField2 release];

textField3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 60, 60, 60)];
textField3.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
textField3.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textField3.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
textField3.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:41];
textField3.secureTextEntry = YES;
textField3.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textField3.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
[self.view addSubview:textField3];
[textField3 release];

textField4 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(235, 60, 60, 60)];
textField4.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
textField4.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textField4.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
textField4.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:41];
textField4.secureTextEntry = YES;
textField4.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textField4.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
[self.view addSubview:textField4];
[textField4 release];

hiddenTF = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
hiddenTF.hidden = YES;
hiddenTF.delegate = self;
hiddenTF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
[self.view addSubview:hiddenTF];
[hiddenTF release];
[hiddenTF becomeFirstResponder];
}

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this can be helpful for other, I solved my problem with this source code on GitHub: [PTPasscodeViewController](https://github.com/lashad/PTPasscodeViewController).
I changed it a little bit to adapt it to my needs and now works greatly :)

If you want to use it, there are all the information about how to use it on the project page or in a file if you've downloaded it ;)

Hope this help!

P.S.: Thanks a lot to Lasha Dolidze to provide this code!

Comment: Beware that PTPasscodeViewController is licensed under the GPL.

Comment: Not bad per se, but a lot (if not all) iOS developers want to sell their app and keep it closed source. The GPL is not compatible with that.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, KVPasscodeViewController (mine), is available here: https://github.com/Koolistov/Passcode (BSD license).

Answer (score 2):

[PINCode 1.0](http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/PINCode-Download-91519.html)